# How to pass cypress environment variable from cucumber feature file?

Tags: cucumber, cypress

I want to pass cypress environment variables from cucumber feature file. But while running scripts in cypress runner getting 404 NOT FOUND error.

Any Ideas please?
Versions used:
"cypress": "^9.5.4",
"cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^4.3.1"

Comment: Please paste code of this feature file.

Answer (score 0):

Below, I show you how to use any variable within a feature file. You only have to replace the variable in the example (which is assetName) by your environment variable.

```
Feature: Business critical scenarios

Verify the proper operation of most critial scearnios

Scenario Outline: Add a asset successfully
    Given I go to the Add Asset tab
    When Validate page title and url
    And I type the valid name <assetName> in the asset input box
    Then I press send button
    And Validate the asset <assetName> is added successfully

Examples:
  | assetName         |
  | "ABCD0000000026"  |
```

**Notes**:

1. In my example the variable within the section Examples and below the field assetName, it's in quotes because the expected variable in my test file and linked with those steps, it's a string. If you are using int you must skip the quotes.
2. If you add more values below ABCD0000000026, your test will run as many times as values you add, like a loop